# Help writing a parametric equation from this complex polar one

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

A particle is moving along the curve $r=4-2\sin(\theta)$ at the moment when $\theta = t^2$. I need to write a x(t) and y(t) function that will model the particle behavior with its x position and y position as a function of time, t.

I've tried converting it to Cartesian and going from there, but I can't figure it out with the multiple degrees of x and y when I do. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta\\
r = 4 - 2 \sin \theta\\
\theta = t^2\\
x = (4 - 2 \sin t^2)(\cos t^2)\\
y = (4 - 2 \sin t^2)(\sin t^2)$